# xampp error reporting

Tags: php, error-handling, xampp

I am using xampp for years, and never had a problem...

Yesterday , while developing a Wordpress site, suddenly xampp stopped error reporting , and started to output empty pages whenever an error occurs. (sometimes, if the error is in an unknown function for example, it just output everything up to that point, and the rest is just blank. (where previously it used to have the error displayed).

Nobody touched php.ini, and `display_errors = On` .
restarted multiple times. no go .

anyone knows what is the problem ? 
Any solution ?

Comment: Check the page source. Sometimes if the error occurs within an element, you end up with something like `<a href="Fatal error: something something something` which doesn't actually display anything when rendered.

Comment: Thanks all, I have found the problem, it was not XAMPP by itself, but a function that I used in order to use PHP myadmin inside the wordpress admin area . once disabled, it all came back to normal. now I only have to understand how and why this happenes ..

Answer (score 1):

run `phpinfo();` to see all error reporting relevant settings (every setting contains `error` in it's name, `error_reporting`, for example).
Find one which set wrong.
grep for it over the code (including .htaccess).

Comment: phpinfo(); will only give me the content of php.ini - which I have already checked manually. almost all of the other files were coded by me , and did not had any change in them...

Comment: errr... did you notice TWO columns in the phpinfo output?

Comment: sure.. always identical on my system. anyhow, thanks for trying to help - I have already commented on my own question that I have found what was causing it (although not the root of the problem)

Comment: I am not talking of "always". I am talking of this very case. If you have some config value changed for the some script, it will be shown in the "Local value" column in the phpinfo() output called in that script. If you are calling phpinfo() somewhere else or just read it's output inattentively - it's your problem, not this function's.

Comment: Thank you, I understood it the first time. when I wrote "always" I meant that they are identical also in this case . and I never blamed phpinfo() for nothing :-) . Like I wrote above , the blame for not outputting the error came from a function that I WROTE , although I still do not know how and why.

Answer (score 0):

do a grep on `ob_start()`, this is the one usually buffering your output